# Adding username and password default on Git

Tags: git

Is it possible to store a remote Git repo's user credentials on my local machine so I don't keep getting asked for them everytime I do a pull etc?

thanks

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use ssh keys and the `git` protocol (over ssh) when cloning:

```
git clone git@git-host.com:user/repo.git
```

If you are using `github` as git server, you can follow this [documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) which describes how to create and use ssh keys.

If you cloned the repo already using the `https` protocol, you can change the origin following these steps:

```
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin git@git-host.com:user/repo.git
```